# TextField in ToolbarItem in macOs stays very small

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, toolbar, nstoolbar

I am trying to put a TextField in the toolbar of my macOs app. However, the constraints I apply via .frame() do not seem to have any effect.
Here is some the test code:

ToolbarTestApp.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct toolbartestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowStyle(.titleBar)
        .windowToolbarStyle(.unified(showsTitle: false))
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    TextField("example", text: $text)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            })
    }
}
```

And here is the result

[image: Small textfield in big toolbar window]

Can anyone tell me how to make the TextField take up the whole width of the toolbar? And if I have to use a NSViewRepresentable, could you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: im having the same problem in iOS , 16xx .. have a text field and a view. using .toolbar and toolbaritem group to .principal ,the text field is shrunk but when tapped or cliked in the simulator it expands.., i needed the expanded proper size from the beginning..

Answer (score 0):

You're not the first to come up with this problem. Apparently, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65891965/how-to-add-a-textfield-to-toolbar-in-swiftui-macos) post also discussed the topic. The way I reproduced your issue and came to a solution is using this content view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Text("Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world! Hello, world!")
                .padding()
                .toolbar(content: {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        TextField("example", text: $text)
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width - 20)
                            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you the screen like this:

[image]

As you can see, the text field expands across the entire window.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately, it does not work properly. The textfield disappears when the window reduces size, and the text within it does not display completely when making the window bigger. See gif here: https://imgur.com/a/UaooSFJ